# How to properly calculate the exact p-value for binomial hypothesis testing (e.g. in Excel)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution, excel

I am confused with calculation of the *p*-value for binomial hypothesis testing when **not** using the normal approximation and its *Z*-statistic.

My hypothesis testing is for the situation when *H*₀: *π* = *π*₀ and *H*₁: *π* ≠ *π*₀. Suppose we have a sample with 101 successes out of 790 trials (*π* = 12.8%). We also have a reference value *π*₀ = 11.7% for the supposed population percentage. I want to calculate the **exact binomial *p*-value for two-sided test**, and I got stuck in the middle.

First, I consider the binomial distribution *B*(790, 0.117) and calculate the probability of observing 101 or more successes (right tail). I use Excel formula `=1 - BINOM.DIST(100, 790, 0.117, TRUE)` which evaluates to 0.185…, but it is not a question of Excel coding, but the question of the theory of calculating.

My problem is that I don’t fully understand what to do next to arrive at *p*-value from this 0.185. Some sources suggest that I should multiply this number by 2, but I’m in doubt: since my binomial distribution is not symmetric, I cannot simply double one-tail probability to get the proper two-sided *p*-value.

I feel like I should calculate *some other* probability for the same binomial distribution and add it to 0.185 go get the *p*-value, but probability of what exactly should it be? Please help me to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have found the answer.

Suppose we have a binomial situation with *n* trials and probability *π*₀ of success. We also have *k* observed successes, so the observed proportion is *π* = *k*/*n*. We want to know whether the difference between *π* and *π*₀ is statistically significant; to be more precise, we want to know the exact *p*-value measuring the level of this significance.

This is *two-sided* binomial test, so the hypotheses are:

- *H*₀: *π* = *π*₀
- *H*₁: *π* ≠ *π*₀

The resulting *p*-value will be the sum of all individual binomial probabilities for all *x* values whose probabilities are no greater than the probability of *k*, *both from the left and right tails* of the distribution. I.e. we need to calculate the sum of all probabilities marked in red in this figure:

[image: p-value illustration]

In Excel, *pₖ* (the probability for *k*) is calculated by the formula `= BINOM.DIST(k, n, π₀, FALSE)`. The condition that, for a given *x*, its probability is no greater than *pₖ* is `BINOM.DIST(x, n, π₀, FALSE) <= pₖ`. We can generate an array of all these *x* values with the formula `= FILTER(SEQUENCE(n + 1, 1, 0), BINOM.DIST(SEQUENCE(n + 1, 1, 0), n, π₀, FALSE) <= pₖ)`. Finally, the sum of their probabilities would be:

```
= SUM(BINOM.DIST(FILTER(SEQUENCE(n + 1, 1, 0), BINOM.DIST(SEQUENCE(n + 1, 1, 0), n, π₀, FALSE) <= pₖ), n, π₀, FALSE))
```

In my particular case with *n* = 790, *k* = 101, and *π*₀ = 11.7% the formula is

```
= SUM(BINOM.DIST(FILTER(SEQUENCE(791, 1, 0), BINOM.DIST(SEQUENCE(791, 1, 0), 790, 0.117, FALSE) <= BINOM.DIST(101, 790, 0.117, FALSE)), 790, 0.117, FALSE))
```

which evaluates to *p*-value = 0.346…. Not too significant, unfortunately, but the method seems to work.